# MBProgressHUD crashing the app while doing work in another thread

Tags: iphone, ios, nsthread, mbprogresshud

I am trying to do some work in thread for which I am using the MBProgressHUD. When I try to do the following code, it is crashing.

```
if ([database databaseNeedsMigration]) {
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
HUD.labelText = @"Upgrading Data";
HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Just relax";
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.taskInProgress = YES;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
[HUD showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
[database migrateDatabase];
} onQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0) completionBlock:^{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

     }];


}
```

However when I try to add a selector to MBProgressHUD with a sleep in the function it works.

Comment: Don't do UI stuff in background threads.

Comment: Can you add the exact exception you're getting? What line is crashing?

Comment: maybe "migrateDatabese" updates part of the UI .. so it needs to be called on the main thread